# How receive URL in MacOS in a simple .app as Browser

Tags: macos, browser

I built a very simple MacOS application called LinkClipper, to allow copy links and just published [here](https://github.com/robertovg/linkclipper). But I got stuck because when I set the application as the default browser in my Mac in order to copy links to the clipboard or when I set it as browser in [Choosy](https://choosy.app/), the URL is never coming as an argument in the script.

I tried assuming the URL was coming as CLI argument or as --arg from the system, but in any case, when the link executes the LinkClipper application you can see in the script [inside the .app](https://github.com/robertovg/LinkClipper/blob/main/apps/withPassthrough/LinkClipper.app/Contents/MacOS/LinkClipper#L3C1-L13), but nothing, it seems browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox...) received the URL from the system in a different way and I can't find the way to make this simple project to work.